Getting 401 trying to create a post even though I'm using an application password
I'm trying to write some basic code that will create a post via Node.js. This is for a WP install hosted by Wordpress.com. I enabled 2FA for the user and made an application password. However, I can't seem to get past:
{
  code: 'rest_cannot_create',
  message: 'Sorry, you are not allowed to create posts as this user.',
  data: { status: 401 }
}

As far as I know, creating the app password should enable simple auth methods to work, but maybe I'm missing something? Here's the code with username/password/host removed:
let username = 'the user name';
let password = '16 digit password';

let auth = 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(username + ':' + password).toString('base64');

let body = {
 title:'new post', 
  content:'content', 
  status:'draft'
};

let resp = await fetch('https://the site/wp-json/wp/v2/posts', {
  method:'POST',
  headers:{
    'Authorization':auth,
    'Content-Type':'application/json',
  },
  body:JSON.stringify(body)
});
let data = await resp.json();
console.log(data);


You are concatenating the word "Basic" twice in the Authorization string.
Once here:
let auth = 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(username + ':' + password).toString('base64');
and again here:
'Authorization':'Basic '+auth,

Good find, but I fixed that, and got the exact same response. I'm going to edit my question.

As an aside, I get the same error even if I intentionally put in bad credentials. Which I suppose makes sense, they don't want the error to be revealing.
